# Oracle Apex How to pass item values in page redirect between applications that are not in session

Tags: oracle, apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm using Oracle Apex 5.1.

Let's say that I have two applications, with id's are 128 and 999. I have one page in application 128:10 that has a button to redirect to a page in application 999:12, sending some values from items on page 128:10 to page items on 999:12.

Page 128:10 is normal DML page, page 999:12 is a modal page, so it opens over the 128:10 page.

Problem is when an item value that is being sent from page 128:10 is changed without submitting the page. Since the redirect button is rendered when the page is loaded, it's not redirecting with current item value, but with original item value. Submitting a page first is not an option.
Setting the button to submit a page, than a branch to page 999:12 doesn't work because page 999:12 is a modal page.

I don't know how or if it is possible to directly access item from page 999:12 that is on 128:10.

Something like `:P12_ITEM := :P10_ITEM` doesn't work since pages are in different applications.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the redirect to work sending current values from page 128:10 to page in 999:12, preferably without a complicated javascript solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Dynamic action and execute it onClick button (P10_MY_URL item should be created as hidden):

1st true action:

```
DECLARE
    l_app number := v('APP_ID');
    l_session number := v('APP_SESSION');
BEGIN
    :P10_MY_URL:= APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(
        p_url => 'f?p=999:12:'||l_session||'::NO::P12_ITEM:&P10_CURRENTPAGE_ITEM.',
        p_checksum_type => 'SESSION');
END;
```

Items to submit should contain any item you want to pass value from, in this case P10_MY_URL,P10_CURRENTPAGE_ITEM

Item to return should be P10_MY_URL

2nd true action:

```
javascript: window.location.href = apex.item('P10_MY_URL').getValue();
```

and thats it.

Comment: This did it. So the original idea of page redirect doesn't work if you need to send changed values from the current page to a modal page in a different application. Instead you can use APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL to dynamically create the url for the modal page, and this url will contain item values from the original page, even if they are changed and not submitted.